# I need an elegant way to normalize a scalar (sort of)

Tags: c#, math

I have a float that can be any value on the positive or negative scale.

If the float is less than 1 or greater than -1 AND not 0, it needs to be rounded to 1 or -1.

I have a function I've made that does the trick but I have a feeling there is an elegant inline mathy way of doing this but I just cant come up with one.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static float NormalizeScalar(float input)
{
    if ((input > -1) && (input < 1))
        return (input == 0) ? 0 : (input < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    return input;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Math.Sign(input)`.

If your input is 0.78 -> returns 1.

If it's 0 -> returns 0.

If it's -0.78 -> returns -1.

Comment: Perfect and elegant. Good job on not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This will indeed "normalize a scalar" perfectly. For my solution I can use **(Math.Abs(input) > 1 ? input : Math.Sign(input))** which does not seem to impact performance any further. For anyone interested in the benchmarks I ran you can find them [here](http://pastebin.com/v8Wstvu3). The results: 1: **350**, 2: **400**, 3: **400** showing that it was only fractionally slower to use the more elegant approach. Thank you!